# BizTalk Receive Location to connect to Azure Blob Storage and receive the file

Tags: biztalk

I have configured the Receive Location with WCF-WebHTTP but the file is not getting picked up from Azure Blob Storage

I have successfully configured Send Port to send the files to Azure Blob. But am not able to do similar steps to receive Files from Azure .

Need to receive the files from Azure Blob and read the file

Comment: Can you show us what the configuration is? Are you getting errors?  What steps did you try, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thank you .
I followed the steps in the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494859/calling-rest-api-to-fetch-csv-data-using-biztalk-wcf-webhttp-adapter                                                                                                      Polling is working fine and created Static TwoWay Send Port  but got the below error  .
'Source: "FileAzure" Send Port: "AzureBlobReceive" URI: "XXXXXXXX" Reason: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  
Please assist  on this

Comment: Am not sure whether this is the right approach for my case. Need to Copy files from Azure Blob and put it in BizTalk Server . Please suggest if there are better approach

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add additional information rather than in the comments

Comment: just wait for biztalk 2020, they will include Azure Blob adapter. Right now what you can do is using scripts/component to download azure blob using task scheduler.

Comment: @EdBangga  BizTalk 2020 is due out until near the end of this year though, and might not be Generally Available until early next year.

Comment: Thanks a lot. , So this can not be done straight forward in Receive Location??

Comment: You might have to do a hybrid solution where you expose a Azure Endpoint Relay from BizTalk and have a logic app trigger of the Azure Blob store that sends it to the Azure Endpoint Relay.